# Want to to create an array of objects to display as components with different values

Tags: angular, typescript

In my HTML I am using *ngFor to display my array of servers. Seriously no clue where to go from here and what I am doing wrong. I have googled for hours but couldn't find the right way to do this. Its just frustrating..

1 First Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-server',
  templateUrl: './servers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servers.component.css']
})
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit {
  serverId: number;
  serverName: string;
  serverStatus: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, status: string) {
    this.serverId = id;
    this.serverName = name;
    this.serverStatus = status;
  }
}
```

2 Second Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-servers',
  templateUrl: './servers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servers.component.css']
})
export class ServersComponent implements OnInit {
  servers: Object[];
  serverObj: Object;


    constructor() {
        this.servers = [];
        this.serverObj = new ServerComponent(0, "testN", "testS");
      }

  createServer() {
      this.servers.push(this.serverObj);
    }
  }
}
```

3 Error Message:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR

src/app/app.module.ts:12:5 - error NG6001: The class 'ServerComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

12     ServerComponent,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/server/server.component.ts:9:14
    9 export class ServerComponent implements OnInit {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'ServerComponent' is declared here.


ERROR

src/app/server/server.component.ts:14:15 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'id' of class 'ServerComponent'.
  Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

14   constructor(id: number, name: string, status: string) {
                 ~~

  src/app/server/server.component.ts:14:19
    14   constructor(id: number, name: string, status: string) {
                         ~~~~~~
    This type is not supported as injection token.
```

Comment: Is there any possibility you could create a StackBlitz with your code? From the code you've provided it is very hard to provide guidance.

Comment: Your first class should just be a normal class. No @Component decorator or ‘implements’.

Comment: For the errors you've included, neither of your component classes are decorated with the [Component decorator](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview#creating-a-component-manually). Once you do that though, your components aren't implementing the OnInit interface and there are other issues. You should try to understand/address them one at a time.

Comment: Have you worked through any of the Angular tutorials on angular.io?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment has a point. Post the contents of the entire file, including imports, otherwise we are missing potentially crucial information.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I have the '@Component' in my project but didnt know it was important to show here so i edited my post to include them

Comment: @MikeOne My first class has a '@Component' because it is a component. It has the HTML that shows my server properties.

Comment: @thief - it is not actually an Angular component, you want to use this just as a simple javascript class. Remove all the angular related stuff there and thing should work. (PS: You might want to follow some tutorials first)

Comment: @MikeOne i see what you mean and i am definitely going to look for some tutorials. However this specific class is really used for more than just a javascript class. It's the server.component.ts to my server.component.html

Comment: I understand the intent you have here, but that is not how it works I’m afraid . You’re probably after a parent child relationship is my guess. But that works on a template level only (you wouldn’t ‘new’ a child like this in a parent). You’ll get there, no worries. You simply miss some fundamental information here.

Comment: Angular can't do dependency injection so it can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component constructors are for dependency injection only. You don't normally create instances of components via JS either, you just add their tags to an html file.

If you want a class with a regular constructor, just use a regular class. If you want to then pass that data from one component to another, there a few ways to do it, depending on your use case.

I can't tell exactly what you're doing but it looks like you need both these components, so you'll need another class to hold the data.

```js
export class Server {
  serverId: number;
  serverName: string;
  serverStatus: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string, status: string) {
    this.serverId = id;
    this.serverName = name;
    this.serverStatus = status;
  }
}
```

You can then instantiate your array of servers like you were trying to do. Normally you use the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook in a component, since the constructor is mainly for DI. That's why components implement the interface by default.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-servers',
  templateUrl: './servers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servers.component.css']
})
export class ServersComponent implements OnInit {
  servers: Server[] = [];

   ngOnInit() {
      this.servers.push(new Server(0, "testN0", "testS0"));
      this.servers.push(new Server(1, "testN1", "testS1"));
      this.servers.push(new Server(2, "testN2", "testS2"));
   }
}
```

To pass a single server to every `ServerComponent` you can do so by adding an `@Input()` property.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-server',
  templateUrl: './servers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./servers.component.css']
})
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() server?: Server;

   ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.server);
   }
}
```

You can also give a default value rather than using a `?`.

`@Input()` allows you to input data into a component via html. `ngFor*` will also let you iterate over the array, creating one component for every entry in the array.

So in **servers.component.html**

```html
<app-server *ngFor="let server of servers" [server]="server"></app-server>
```

Square brackets indicate an input property.

This will create three instances of `ServerComponent` when you instantiate a `ServersComponent`.

Comment: You can also use `@Inject(MY_TOKEN)` to inject other things into the constructor. For example `@Inject(MY_TOKEN) serverId: number`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I think that only works if `MY_TOKEN` is a class marked with `@Injectable()` no? I believe all constructor parameters implicitly include an `@Inject()`, but the type annotation is used as the token if it's not explicitly included. ie. `constructor(public engine: Engine)` is same as `constructor(@Inject(Engine) engine:Engine)`

Comment: Inject can contain anything.

Comment: Mmmm don't think so, if the token is not provided as an injectable you will get the exact error in this question: `error NG2003: No suitable injection token`. You can create an injectable that returns anything, but you can't just inject anything.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/immutable-injectors?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftokens.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, you had to create an injectable and provide it with the providers array. I think we are saying the same thing. I think the misunderstanding came from the wording of 'inject other things' - you can't just inject a number, you have to create an injectable and then provide it to the component, at which point you can assign the value of a number to the injectable. In the context of this question, the first comment made it seem like using `@Inject()` would somehow help here, so I guess I misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: Yeah sorry my fault I forgot to mention that you needed to create an injectable and then assign a number to it. But if the OP wants to use numbers it needs to be done the way I did it in the example.